# Change wallet fom basic to advanced

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Noob here.
I installed "Monero-Wallet-gui.AppImage" on my linux box, after quickly going through the prompts I created a basic account using an external node. What if I changed my mind and now I want the advanced settings ? how would I do that ? uninstall, reinstall, change my prompt responses and log into my previously created account ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the basic wallet and let it synchronize
2. Click on the "exit" button at the top left of the window (the symbol is like a door with an arrow)
3. There you should see a "Change wallet mode" button